# Is there any way to detect HTML 5 Semantic tags support in mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, modernizr

Is there any way to detect HTML 5 **Semantic** tags support in mobile browsers?

Tags like:

`<section>`, `<nav>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<hgroup>`, `<header>`, `<footer>`

I'm making mobile website with 2 versions like m.facebook.com and touch.facebook.com and I want to redirect to supported mobiles. and in touch version I'm using HTML 5 tags.

And for example Android 1.6 doesn't have HTML5 support and still in use. So i want to redirect all Android 1.6 devices to m.mobileversion.com not to touch.mobileversion.com

Comment: What do you mean by *support*? Apart from IE, how is it possible to 'not support' those elements? Also, do you have a use for hgroup? Are you actually using the outline algorithm? Unless you are validating and testing your site's outlines, there's no point even using most of the elements.Simple answer: None of those elements currently adds anything whatsoever to your page. If support is bothering you, just serve divs and spans to absolutely everyone and don't monkey with myths that you can achieve something by using some newer wrapper elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use those tags for all browsers/platforms. First, you need to make sure those elements are recognized as block level elements which is all most browsers need since the elements themselves have no special meaning (semantics aside).

```
section, 
nav, 
article, 
aside, 
hgroup, 
header, 
footer {
display: block;
}
```

Then, for IE, just include the HTML5 shim in your page which uses a few lines of js to create these elements:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Don't forget to set your doctype to the HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of methods of detecting HTML5 element support for a browser.

http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html